# Physically hide time at top of iPhone in status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, time, case

I want to be able to hide the time on iPhone at bedtime. It seems there are no settings that will remove the time or hide the status bar. Is there a case out there that can slot over the top left of the phone and physically hide the time?

Comment: What about wallet style cover ?

Comment: How about having the screen sleep so it is not illuminated at all? Placing it screen-down should also work.